# Exoplayer: video does not resize to fit when initial orientation is portrait

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, exoplayer

I am running into an issue where the Exoplayer playerview isn't initially fitting the containing frame, and maintaining the video's aspect ratio in portrait.  The view is only resized correctly when rotating the device to landscape, and then rotating back to portrait orientation.

Note, this is a React Native application and the orientation for the rest of the app is locked to portrait.  In this case, only the player is to freely move between different orientations.

What I have tried so far:

- set the app `resize_mode` to `fit` on the player view (both programmatically & via layout xml)
- removed an forced aspect ratio on the player views -- previously, we had hardcoded to `16:9`
- have set the `videoScalingMode` on the exoplayer instance to `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT`
- as I mentioned above, the default orientation for the rest of the app is `portrait`.  In the app manifest, I removed the `android:ScreenOrientation="portrait"` setting for the MainActivity.

I am at a little bit of a loss right now.  My understand is, setting the `resize_mode` to fit as the default should work when the player view is created.  Is there something with how the layout is created? Any help is appreciated.

For reference, here are parts of the code for the player:

**video.xml** - layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/exoplayerview_video"
                app:resize_mode="fit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```

**Main Activity** - android manifest (partial)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:extractNativeLibs="${extractNativeLibs}"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
            android:value="com.reactnative.googlecast.GoogleCastOptionsProvider" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.reactnative.googlecast.RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="${castReceiverId}" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${google_maps_api_key}" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

 ............
```

---

Here are some screenshots of what I am seeing vs. what is intended:

**Initial Portrait issue - resize mode not respected**:
[image]

**Expected player view sizing**:
[image]

---

Additional notes:

- When taking a screenshot of the player, the player view re-orients itself & lays out correctly (note: this is not re-rendering the react component, only the native player layer is updating for some reason).  It seems that any configurationChange is causing a redraw of the player view -- so backgrounding+foregrounding, orientation change ..etc, subsequently orients the player correctly in portrait.
- `compileSdkVersion`: 33
- `targetSdkVersion`: 33
- exoplayer version: `2.13.1`

Comment: Also noticing that code that works fine in API 31 seems to have aspect ratio broken with API 33. Still looking for solution.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AspectRatioFrameLayout with mode RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/AspectRatioFrameLayout.html#RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue, as the video is still stretched when initially started